# Reorder dataframe column that includes specific names in specific order

Tags: r

I have the data below which has 1044 rows. The `id` contains in the first 87 rows 87 unique names with a specific order. Then from row 88 the same names with same order are repeated until row 175 and so on until row 1044.

Now I want to reorder the dataset by `id` by gathering all the same names as many times they exist (1044/87=12) but with the same order they exist in the initial dataframe so for example the first 4 rows of my new data will be `Name1,Name88,Name175,Name262` and so on..

```
# Creating a sequence of 87 unique names
unique_names <- paste0("Name", 1:87)

# Repeat the unique names to get 1044 rows
repeated_names <- rep(unique_names, length.out = 1044)

# Generating random numeric values for the second column
random_values <- runif(1044) # Change parameters according to your requirements

# Creating the dataframe
data <- data.frame(id = repeated_names, values = random_values)
```

Comment: Aren't you just sorting by name then? Like `data[order(with(data, factor(id, unique(id)))),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to sort the dataframe by `id`, but use the order in which `id` first appears. You can do this with the following one-liner (note the row names are in the specified order):

```r
data[order(with(data, factor(id, unique(id)))),]
#>          id       values
#> 1     Name1 5.263096e-01
#> 88    Name1 8.578252e-01
#> 175   Name1 3.479284e-01
#> 262   Name1 5.296923e-01
#> 349   Name1 1.085899e-01
#> 436   Name1 3.922578e-01
#> 523   Name1 3.078238e-01
#> 610   Name1 6.257815e-01
#> 697   Name1 6.245708e-01
#> 784   Name1 1.373686e-01
#> 871   Name1 7.947614e-01
#> 958   Name1 1.039647e-02
#> 2     Name2 5.335738e-01
#> 89    Name2 3.393713e-01
#> 176   Name2 6.222394e-01
#> 263   Name2 3.016773e-01
#> 350   Name2 8.678417e-01
#> 437   Name2 3.494456e-01
#> 524   Name2 2.297880e-01
#> 611   Name2 4.217584e-01
#> 698   Name2 2.800260e-01
#> 785   Name2 5.557307e-01
#> 872   Name2 4.699509e-01
#> 959   Name2 2.238131e-01
#> 3     Name3 1.496468e-01
#> 90    Name3 2.112112e-01
#> 177   Name3 3.951932e-01
#> 264   Name3 7.924696e-01
#> 351   Name3 5.275981e-01
#> 438   Name3 6.269663e-02
#> 525   Name3 2.767372e-01
#> 612   Name3 1.210715e-01
#> 699   Name3 4.055651e-01
#> 786   Name3 6.611223e-01
#> 873   Name3 7.281214e-01
#> 960   Name3 6.972039e-01
#> 4     Name4 5.093340e-01
#> 91    Name4 6.280333e-02
#> 178   Name4 5.187594e-01
#> 265   Name4 5.429091e-01
#> 352   Name4 7.461857e-01
#> 439   Name4 4.905147e-01
#> 526   Name4 6.319581e-01
#> 613   Name4 2.297919e-03
#> 700   Name4 1.401638e-01
#> 787   Name4 2.014982e-01
#> 874   Name4 2.428456e-01
#> 961   Name4 7.313308e-01
#> 5     Name5 7.550440e-01
#> 92    Name5 5.882545e-01
#> 179   Name5 7.004829e-01
#> 266   Name5 2.107642e-01
#> 353   Name5 3.826765e-01
#> 440   Name5 3.326024e-01
#> 527   Name5 4.256065e-01
#> 614   Name5 4.536161e-01
#> 701   Name5 5.773471e-01
#> 788   Name5 8.345956e-01
#> 875   Name5 9.561155e-01
#> 962   Name5 4.040662e-01
#> 6     Name6 8.341755e-01
#> 93    Name6 6.813080e-02
#> 180   Name6 2.466805e-02
#> 267   Name6 5.896061e-01
#> 354   Name6 7.327837e-01
#> 441   Name6 2.120784e-01
#> 528   Name6 3.720217e-01
#> 615   Name6 8.222597e-01
#> 702   Name6 3.182815e-01
#> 789   Name6 7.549763e-01
#> 876   Name6 4.358885e-01
#> 963   Name6 2.613530e-02
#> 7     Name7 9.598459e-01
#> 94    Name7 7.708241e-01
#> 181   Name7 9.302728e-01
#> 268   Name7 4.958397e-02
#> 355   Name7 4.876716e-01
#> 442   Name7 1.168121e-01
#> 529   Name7 8.276435e-03
#> 616   Name7 7.948343e-01
#> 703   Name7 2.227685e-01
#> 790   Name7 5.726201e-02
#> 877   Name7 8.184423e-01
#> 964   Name7 5.175537e-01
#> 8     Name8 2.331493e-01
#> 95    Name8 3.309616e-01
#> 182   Name8 5.721188e-01
#> 269   Name8 5.770252e-01
#> 356   Name8 4.404109e-01
#> 443   Name8 7.156175e-01
#> 530   Name8 4.182836e-01
#> 617   Name8 5.414753e-01
#> 704   Name8 5.216959e-01
#> 791   Name8 7.068611e-01
#> 878   Name8 3.350511e-01
#> 965   Name8 4.170534e-01
#> 9     Name9 6.851374e-01
#> 96    Name9 5.360740e-01
#> 183   Name9 9.975251e-01
#> 270   Name9 7.584329e-01
#> 357   Name9 1.268428e-01
#> 444   Name9 9.640549e-01
#> 531   Name9 9.471353e-01
#> 618   Name9 5.612151e-01
#> 705   Name9 9.001855e-01
#> 792   Name9 9.447749e-01
#> 879   Name9 8.363992e-01
#> 966   Name9 8.243104e-01
#> 10   Name10 7.763435e-01
#> 97   Name10 9.070740e-01
#> 184  Name10 4.145050e-01
#> 271  Name10 9.382179e-01
#> 358  Name10 4.985626e-01
#> 445  Name10 2.076228e-01
#> 532  Name10 3.329333e-01
#> 619  Name10 2.779036e-01
#> 706  Name10 4.817758e-02
#> 793  Name10 9.687587e-01
#> 880  Name10 2.562227e-01
#> 967  Name10 2.570376e-01
#> 11   Name11 9.118810e-01
#> 98   Name11 2.730810e-01
#> 185  Name11 8.106561e-02
#> 272  Name11 4.455183e-01
#> 359  Name11 4.976100e-01
#> 446  Name11 8.723689e-01
#> 533  Name11 2.148719e-01
#> 620  Name11 9.317240e-01
#> 707  Name11 5.467247e-01
#> 794  Name11 7.658968e-01
#> 881  Name11 1.716942e-02
#> 968  Name11 7.674486e-01
#> 12   Name12 3.024189e-01
#> 99   Name12 3.765192e-01
#> 186  Name12 8.825763e-01
#> 273  Name12 4.756373e-01
#> 360  Name12 2.877821e-01
#> 447  Name12 1.922460e-01
#> 534  Name12 9.172091e-01
#> 621  Name12 7.716123e-01
#> 708  Name12 4.821892e-01
#> 795  Name12 1.592853e-01
#> 882  Name12 7.684508e-01
#> 969  Name12 7.102600e-01
#> 13   Name13 1.321232e-01
#> 100  Name13 2.010518e-01
#> 187  Name13 3.728789e-01
#> 274  Name13 3.621436e-01
#> 361  Name13 8.102981e-01
#> 448  Name13 5.125705e-02
#> 535  Name13 7.476368e-01
#> 622  Name13 5.447666e-01
#> 709  Name13 9.280155e-01
#> 796  Name13 7.221189e-01
#> 883  Name13 5.128152e-01
#> 970  Name13 1.051755e-01
#> 14   Name14 8.609264e-01
#> 101  Name14 1.926538e-01
#> 188  Name14 4.579446e-01
#> 275  Name14 7.701247e-01
#> 362  Name14 9.721063e-01
#> 449  Name14 7.200982e-01
#> 536  Name14 2.648320e-01
#> 623  Name14 2.628744e-01
#> 710  Name14 7.331427e-01
#> 797  Name14 5.759444e-01
#> 884  Name14 8.684383e-01
#> 971  Name14 4.480472e-01
#> 15   Name15 6.021514e-01
#> 102  Name15 8.681113e-01
#> 189  Name15 2.981368e-01
#> 276  Name15 5.467562e-01
#> 363  Name15 4.559119e-01
#> 450  Name15 7.069873e-01
#> 537  Name15 3.087303e-01
#> 624  Name15 1.464224e-01
#> 711  Name15 3.651410e-01
#> 798  Name15 8.863425e-01
#> 885  Name15 5.381808e-01
#> 972  Name15 2.372111e-01
#> 16   Name16 4.144494e-01
#> 103  Name16 1.602388e-01
#> 190  Name16 4.672472e-01
#> 277  Name16 2.816833e-01
#> 364  Name16 2.352374e-01
#> 451  Name16 4.661067e-01
#> 538  Name16 2.160984e-01
#> 625  Name16 7.831634e-01
#> 712  Name16 7.545236e-01
#> 799  Name16 8.047031e-01
#> 886  Name16 6.481207e-01
#> 973  Name16 3.839450e-01
#> 17   Name17 2.892806e-01
#> 104  Name17 2.883199e-01
#> 191  Name17 5.207887e-01
#> 278  Name17 9.798556e-02
#> 365  Name17 5.507378e-01
#> 452  Name17 6.463473e-01
#> 539  Name17 4.036830e-01
#> 626  Name17 9.142881e-01
#> 713  Name17 1.072295e-01
#> 800  Name17 1.859526e-01
#> 887  Name17 1.441799e-02
#> 974  Name17 8.361656e-01
#> 18   Name18 5.554867e-01
#> 105  Name18 8.138222e-01
#> 192  Name18 7.922891e-02
#> 279  Name18 5.890455e-01
#> 366  Name18 9.743380e-01
#> 453  Name18 9.578815e-01
#> 540  Name18 1.108237e-02
#> 627  Name18 1.159907e-01
#> 714  Name18 6.517556e-01
#> 801  Name18 2.788639e-02
#> 888  Name18 4.473165e-01
#> 975  Name18 4.117293e-01
#> 19   Name19 3.502466e-01
#> 106  Name19 1.877713e-02
#> 193  Name19 2.849907e-01
#> 280  Name19 6.290562e-01
#> 367  Name19 2.657069e-01
#> 454  Name19 5.852346e-01
#> 541  Name19 2.652137e-01
#> 628  Name19 7.264965e-01
#> 715  Name19 4.858167e-01
#> 802  Name19 9.396374e-02
#> 889  Name19 8.324111e-01
#> 976  Name19 2.232743e-01
#> 20   Name20 9.637388e-01
#> 107  Name20 9.724821e-01
#> 194  Name20 3.021156e-01
#> 281  Name20 7.370453e-01
#> 368  Name20 6.006101e-01
#> 455  Name20 3.364321e-01
#> 542  Name20 7.470931e-01
#> 629  Name20 5.756818e-01
#> 716  Name20 1.144363e-02
#> 803  Name20 6.223516e-01
#> 890  Name20 5.505761e-01
#> 977  Name20 1.757959e-01
#> ...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method of turning the first column into factors in the desired order and then using the `order()` function to sort.

Here is your example, but using a small sample for demonstration purposes.

```
# Creating a sequence of 87 unique names
unique_names <- paste0("Name", 1:5)

# Repeat the unique names to get 1044 rows
repeated_names <- rep(unique_names, length.out = 20)

# Generating random numeric values for the second column
random_values <- runif(20) # Change parameters according to your requirements

# Creating the dataframe
data <- data.frame(id = repeated_names, values = random_values)

#convert id in factors in the original order of the first rows
data$id <- factor(data$id, levels=data$id[1:5])

answer <-data[order(data$id),]
answer

      id     values
1  Name1 0.91407438
6  Name1 0.88835351
11 Name1 0.66129609
16 Name1 0.31937027
2  Name2 0.87281847
7  Name2 0.01204243
12 Name2 0.29501657
17 Name2 0.66134983
3  Name3 0.46970367
8  Name3 0.62974563
13 Name3 0.29550490
18 Name3 0.90043110
4  Name4 0.62597839
9  Name4 0.64886806
14 Name4 0.61533939
19 Name4 0.52197769
5  Name5 0.03909647
10 Name5 0.03930761
15 Name5 0.58545074
20 Name5 0.37939068
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try `order` like this

```
idx <- order(as.integer(gsub("\\D+", "", data$id)))
out <- transform(
    data[idx, ],
    newId = paste0("Name", idx)
)
```

and you will see the first `24` rows as below for example

```
> head(out, 24)
       id     values   newId
1   Name1 0.89669720   Name1
88  Name1 0.71112122  Name88
175 Name1 0.39135928 Name175
262 Name1 0.52398608 Name262
349 Name1 0.17180008 Name349
436 Name1 0.10505014 Name436
523 Name1 0.70897520 Name523
610 Name1 0.95095101 Name610
697 Name1 0.55931027 Name697
784 Name1 0.73093288 Name784
871 Name1 0.07676579 Name871
958 Name1 0.88375226 Name958
2   Name2 0.26550866   Name2
89  Name2 0.12169192  Name89
176 Name2 0.38049389 Name176
263 Name2 0.31714467 Name263
350 Name2 0.36918946 Name350
437 Name2 0.80168771 Name437
524 Name2 0.34855035 Name524
611 Name2 0.10664832 Name611
698 Name2 0.78909447 Name698
785 Name2 0.47248792 Name785
872 Name2 0.42144608 Name872
959 Name2 0.18768935 Name959
```

Comment: "Name" is just for the rep. example the actual values are like Paul,Bob Jack etc